# 'IonicSignaturePadModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova, signaturepad

- npm install ionicsignaturepad
- add IonicSignaturePadModule to app module

How to solve "'IonicSignaturePadModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class" error.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the last update's date It seems that the library is not compatible with IVY, and Angular has deprecated the legacy View Engine in recent versions.